# How to add custom logic to ASP.NET CORE 6 Identity sign-in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to wrap my head around how Identity works, and how to customize it.

I have an existing DB and website (asp.net, not core), and then the new system (asp.net core v6). I don't want to use EF so I've implemented custom IUserStore/IUserPasswordStore/IUserEmailStore/etc.

**Situation:**
I have some custom code (in SQL/stored-proc) that the old system runs on sign-in, which checks certain domain-specific data (eg User.IsHappy = 1 AND User.NumTimesTheyWereNiceToMe > 3), as well as creating sign-in records (ie INSERT INTO UserSignedIn...). I need to do the same thing in the new system (using Identity).

**Issue:**
Where do I run my custom query? In the old system I didn't use Identity, so I just called the stored-proc (which checks credentials/data/etc, creates signedin record, and returns signin result) and then I'd create auth cookie/etc.

With Identity I'm guessing I should override SignInManager.PreSignInCheck to check the user data as needed (and customize IUserStore to pull that data), and also override [SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs#L385) and if base.CheckPasswordSignInAsync returns success then make a separate call to the DB in order to insert my UserSignedIn record?

**Is this the correct approach, or is there a more sensible way?**
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could implement an `IUserConfirmation` service, set `IdentityOptions.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true` and enforce any rule you want.

Comment: Is it your imaginary implementation plan or already implemented? Are you getting any blocking?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Haven't implemented any SignInManager overrides yet. Just IUserStore/etc. PS Why do you think blocking could be an issue?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I guess IUserConfirmation could work for pre-checks, though the pre-checks aren't all confirmation related and so could be confusing. But still don't know where to insert a UserSignedIn DB record. Feel like I'm missing something with Identity flow.

Comment: There's also `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Events`, which you could use for logging.